# Is there a way I can add in the url the name of the component i have in a page as a fragment in a multiple step page?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

For example, I have a checkout process that has multiple steps, and I would like the url to be something like: /checkout/personal-details; /checkout/products; /checkout/payment. And I don't know how can I do that without creating multiple pages. I dont't eant to do a redirect. Also, it would be fine if I could have hash in the url, for example: /checkout/#payment.

Also, those steps are react components: payment, personal-details etc.

Right now i have a state that changes the current step, but when i refresh the page is moves back to the first step, and thats why I think hash location could help me.

```
{step === 0 ? <Component1/> : ''}
{step === 1 ? <Component2 /> : ''}
```

Comment: you want all these process to be happening inside single page without any redirection ? kindly be more specific on what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes I want the process be in the same page, without redirection. Something with hash location would help me, I edited the question to be more specific